# Background of cell in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, cell

I've been playing around with datagridviews for a bit and a question has came up.
-> Doesn't changing a cells background work out of the CellFormatting event.
I've tried this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, dataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals(dnsList.First<String>()))
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        cell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(194, 235, 211);
    }
}
```

Which works perfectly, whereas this:

```
private void ApplyColoring()
{
    if (dataGridView1.DataSource != null)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridRow.Cells[dnsList.First<String>()];
            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(194, 235, 211);
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging tells me everything is sound, null-reference-or-whatever-exception-wise...
Any tips?

Comment: When do you call the ApplyColoring method?

Comment: I'd like to apply it after a BackgroundWorker finishes running. So in the backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted. This bgworker gets run via a button, so I've tried to use the b_Click(..) event as well, with the same results (nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform the coloring in the [`CellPainting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting.aspx) event, rather than `CellFormatting`, which is intended for formatting the value of the cell

Comment: Ah, that would be much better indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest calling your method from grid's DataBindingComplete event. Call from BackgroundWorker is probably too early and DataGridView.Rows are not initialized yet.

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
      ApplyColoring();
}
```

Comment: Nah, that way it keeps getting triggered 5000million times, I solved it using a delegate :)

Comment: Delegate called from where? Maybe you could edit your answer and explain your solution? :)

Comment: A delegate from the RunWorkerCompleted event; this.Invoke((Action)delegate { ApplyColoring(); });

Comment: Interesting. This event is called from the same thread as main form so I see no difference when calling using Invoke.